# Different colums to select depending on third column

Tags: sql

I have a database where I need to select different columns depending on a value in column 1.

If column 1 = 1 then select a, b, c from database

if column 1 = 2 then select d, e, f from database

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select a, b, c from table1 where column1 = 1
union all
select d, e, f from table1 where column1 = 2
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
select (case when col1 = 1 then a else d end),
       (case when col1 = 1 then b else e end),
       (case when col1 = 1 then c else f end)
from t
where col1 in (1, 2);
```

Note:  This assumes that the column pairs (`a`/`d` and so on) are compatible with respect to their types.